# Sampled data occurs at one day response

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Dont know why, but i cant create an issue at google public tracker issuetracker.google.com,
this error occurs when i click create Error: The following field(s) have invalid values: must be a comma separated list of issue IDs

I have an application which gets Google Analytics metadata and statistics for a couple dozens google users and them profiles from Management and Reporting API.

Everything was ok for a long period (several month), but yesterday
one of google profile(view) started getting sampled data
here is down below 3 requests, difference are in metrics, but date interval still 03 June and responses are Sampled:true

1.request:

```
{dimensions=ga:adContent,ga:date, end-date=2017-06-03, filters=ga:adContent!=(not set);ga:source!~^(yandex.*|google.*)$, ids=ga:<hidden>, include-empty-rows=false, max-results=10000, metrics=ga:goal18Completions,ga:goal19Completions,ga:goal20Completions, quotaUser=<hidden>, samplingLevel=HIGHER_PRECISION, sort=-ga:adContent,ga:date, start-date=2017-06-03, start-index=1}
```

2.request:

```
{dimensions=ga:adContent,ga:date, end-date=2017-06-03, filters=ga:adContent!=(not set);ga:source!~^(yandex.*|google.*)$, ids=ga:<hidden>, include-empty-rows=false, max-results=10000, metrics=ga:goal8Completions,ga:goal9Completions,ga:goal10Completions,ga:goal11Completions,ga:goal12Completions,ga:goal13Completions,ga:goal14Completions,ga:goal15Completions,ga:goal16Completions,ga:goal17Completions, quotaUser=<hidden>, samplingLevel=HIGHER_PRECISION, sort=-ga:adContent,ga:date, start-date=2017-06-03, start-index=1}
```

3.request:

```
{dimensions=ga:adContent,ga:date, end-date=2017-06-03, filters=ga:adContent!=(not set);ga:source!~^(yandex.*|google.*)$, ids=ga:<hidden>, include-empty-rows=false, max-results=10000, metrics=ga:sessions,ga:newUsers,ga:bounces,ga:goal1Completions,ga:goal2Completions,ga:goal3Completions,ga:goal4Completions,ga:goal5Completions,ga:goal6Completions,ga:goal7Completions, quotaUser=<hidden>, samplingLevel=HIGHER_PRECISION, sort=-ga:adContent,ga:date, start-date=2017-06-03, start-index=1}
```

I know account,property,profile ids, but i dont want write it here
Any thoughts ?

Comment: You could try simplifying the request. 1. drop the `ga:date` dimension as it is only for one day. 2. split up the `ga:goalXXCompletions` into different requests. 3. Try doing the filtering client side if possible. Check the `sapleSpaceSize` to see how close you are to the sampling threshold. In the end there may not be anything you can do. For single-use reports, you can download an unsampled report. For ongoing reporting, you can build a custom table.

Comment: Thank you, I just tried everything you said, nothing helped.

Comment: I made vary simple requests, like that (one metric per request!): {dimensions=ga:adContent, end-date=2017-06-03, filters=ga:adContent!=(not set), ids=<hidden>, include-empty-rows=false, max-results=10000, metrics=ga:goal7Completions, quotaUser=<hidden>, start-date=2017-06-03, start-index=1}

Comment: I wanna remind you here. Other dates for this profile(view) getting data without sampling, with all filters and parameters and 10 metrics per request! Something wrong at server  google server side i guess... Any Google team  is here ?

Comment: During the day (3-rd June) data was not sampled, but after midnight between 3 and 4 June, we started getting sampled data for 3rd June